# Set image on tableView Cell size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `tableView` Cell size and need to set image on `tableView cell`., but image not set of define the Cell size (following code into `tableView`  Cell size stored `cellSize` variable).
My Code is...,

```
CGRect cellSize = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cell.imageView.frame = cellSize;
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_black.png"];
```

above code in image not set image `properly` in `tableView Cell.`

So, How to set image on `TableView` `Cell`?

Comment: what do you mean not set properly.? please elaborate

Comment: what is wrong in accepting the answer? since u have already accepted it???

Comment: Are you trying to set an image as background?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to say that the image u are setting in each cell is not getting displayed at the right position then u can try doing the following:

first create a prototype cell and position the `UIImageView` at the right place in the cell u want and go to the scale properties of `UIImage` and note down the co-ordinates... then

instead of

```
CGRect cellSize = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cell.imageView.frame = cellSize;
```

this you can write the code as follows:

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

ex.

```
CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect cellSize = cell.frame;
cell.imageView.frame = cellSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView allow ] init];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageName:@"imgName"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
```